# What do you call someone or a group of people who split off from a main group?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What is a single word for someone or a group of people who split off from a main group because they're dissatisfied with its state?

I was thinking something along the lines of mutiny, but that's a bit too extreme.

For example: A group of students split off from the main robotics team and formed their own. The original team did something while the ______ (splitters?) did something else.

Comment: "Splinter group" is another term.

Comment: What @HotLicks said. You can also say *splitters* or *dissenters*.

Comment: I ended up going with dissenters. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything that is a synonym of *faction*:

> band, bloc, bunch, cabal, camp, caucus, cell, circle, clan, clique, club, coalition, combination, combine, combo, concern, conclave, confederacy, conspiracy, contingent, coterie, crew, crowd, design, division, entente, gang, guild, insiders, intrigue, junta, knot, lobby, machine, minority, mob, network, offshoot, outfit, partnership, party, pressure group, ring, schism, sect, section, sector, set, side, splinter group, team, unit, wing.

[Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/faction)

Answer (score 3):

**Schismatic**, as defined [here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=schismatics)

> A schismatic is a person who creates or incites schism in an
>   organization or who is a member of a splinter group.

**schism** is defined [here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=schism+definition) as

> a split or division between strongly opposed sections or parties,
>   caused by differences in opinion or belief

For example:  A small group split off from the hiking club; these *schismatics* were determined on multi-day hikes above timberline. The rest of the hiking club wanted easy, one-day hikes, followed by beer in the shade.

Note that a schism is caused by a strong difference about what to do or about what is true, good or right.  You don't become a schismatic because you prefer to meet on Thursdays instead of Tuesdays or have some other minor disagreement.

Answer (score 0):

A minority group that is in opposition to the majority (of the same party) is normally referred to as a faction:

> ***faction:***
>
> a group or clique within a larger group, party, government, organization, or the like

[faction](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/faction?s=t)

Comment: "Faction" implies that the smaller group is still contained within the larger group. I want a word which suggests that the smaller group has completely split off from the larger group.

Answer (score 0):

The following might be used alone or as adjectives with the previous suggestions:

- [**progressives**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/progressive) - [Those] Favoring or promoting change or innovation
- [rebels](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rebel?q=rebels) - A person (persons) who rises in opposition ... against an
  established government
- [revolutionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/revolutionary) - A person (persons) who works for
  or engages in political revolution
- [mavericks](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/maverick) - An unorthodox or
  independent-minded person(s)